# Whitespace disappear for dynamically inserted content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple javascript setup that creates or removes fields depending upon how many the user wants. But when the user clicks the add button to create another field, the space between the fields and elements completely disappears. There's no padding or margin applied on it and even if you do apply a margin, the difference still remains.

Here's the part that's repeated

```
<div class="tax-cont">
  <input type="text" class="form-control inline-field md" placeholder="Tax Name">
  <div class="input-group inline-group md">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value">
    <label class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-percent"></i></label>
  </div>
  <a class="addRemove btn btn-success btn-round btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
</div>
```

And javascript

```
  // Add or Remove additional departure dates
  var taxContent = '<div class="tax-cont"><input type="text" class="form-control inline-field md" placeholder="Tax Name"><div class="input-group inline-group md"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"><label class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-percent"></i></label></div><a class="addRemove btn btn-danger btn-round btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a></div>';

  $('.tax-cont .addRemove.btn-success').on('click', function(){
    var lastTaxbox = $('.tax-cont').last();
    lastTaxbox.after($(taxContent));
  });
  $('.form-group').on('click', '.btn-danger', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
```

Here's how it looks

[image: Screenshot]

I can't figure out why this is happening at all. Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/VeeK727/pen/qaYXpv) to demonstrate.

Comment: It's because of `display:inline-block` issue: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: you want the new ones with the space or the first one without it?

Comment: yeah, it is probably because of that. in html panel you have spaces/tabs/newlines and that makes this "false" margin effect. In javascript there isn't spaces/tabs/newlines and that is why you don't have any margin.

Comment: That seems obvious. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because of the way `inline` and `inline-block` elements behave when it comes to whitespace. In your original `html` source there's a new line between the `<input>` and `<div>`. Which is whitespace and which will result in a whitespace between the two elements on your page.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control inline-field md" placeholder="Tax Name"> <!-- new line -->
<div class="input-group inline-group md"> ... </div>
```

However, when you use Javascript to add elements to your `DOM`, there's no whitespace `node` added. So it will just stick the two together. If you'd remove the new line from your original source, the two inputs will be stuck together as well.

As a solution you could use `margin-right` on the `<input>` or `margin-left` on the following `<div>` to make sure all rows maintain the same spacing.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by others, the reason there's no space between the inserted set is, there's no space between their code. Thanks to nicholas for sharing the [link](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-eleme%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bnts) that explains it well.

To fix the problem, I added white-space in the javascript code (`&nbsp;`) which produces the same space as the original DOM.

```
var taxContent = '<div class="tax-cont"><input type="text" class="form-control inline-field md" placeholder="Tax Name">&nbsp;<div class="input-group inline-group md"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"><label class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-percent"></i></label></div>&nbsp;<a class="addRemove btn btn-danger btn-round btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a></div>';
```